# Get classic user interface on eclipse mars

Tags: eclipse

When I installed Eclipse Mars on my Arch Linux x64 I was shocked how the user interface changed compared to Luna and previous.

If you're wondering what I'm talking about see yourself:

Mars:

[image]

Luna (and previous):

[image]

Does anyone know how I can get the classic user interface back on Eclipse Mars?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=453128) bug

Comment: Thanks, I'm using xfce, too. So it will be this bug. If you write it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be Eclipse bug [453128](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=453128) which is currently not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the following workaround to get a usable interface. You need to create two files in eclipse folder: gtkrc-2.0 and eclipse.sh. The first contains settings for GTK, the second lunches eclipse with these settings.

Contents below:

**gtkrc-2.0**

```
style "gtkcompact" {
    font_name="Sans 9"
    GtkButton::default_border={0,0,0,0}
    GtkButton::default_outside_border={0,0,0,0}
    GtkButtonBox::child_min_width=0
    GtkButtonBox::child_min_heigth=0
    GtkButtonBox::child_internal_pad_x=0
    GtkButtonBox::child_internal_pad_y=0
    GtkMenu::vertical-padding=1
    GtkMenuBar::internal_padding=0
    GtkMenuItem::horizontal_padding=4
    GtkToolbar::internal-padding=0
    GtkToolbar::space-size=0
    GtkOptionMenu::indicator_size=0
    GtkOptionMenu::indicator_spacing=0
    GtkPaned::handle_size=4
    GtkRange::trough_border=0
    GtkRange::stepper_spacing=0
    GtkScale::value_spacing=0
    GtkScrolledWindow::scrollbar_spacing=0
    GtkExpander::expander_size=10
    GtkExpander::expander_spacing=0
    GtkTreeView::vertical-separator=0
    GtkTreeView::horizontal-separator=0
    GtkTreeView::expander-size=8
    GtkTreeView::fixed-height-mode=TRUE
    GtkWidget::focus_padding=0
}

style "gtkcompactextra" {
    xthickness=0
    ythickness=0
}

class "GtkWidget" style "gtkcompact"
#class "GtkButton" style "gtkcompactextra"
class "GtkToolbar" style "gtkcompactextra"
class "GtkPaned" style "gtkcompactextra"
```

**eclipse.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

PWD="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
SWT_GTK3=0 GTK2_RC_FILES=${PWD}/gtkrc-2.0 ${PWD}/eclipse & 2>1
```

Comment: Thanks that looks promising, will try this next time I use my pc.